# mysql query not showing result

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone help me to solve this mysql query problem

```
$rela=mysql_query("SELECT * 
      FROM  pvl_posts 
      WHERE (title LIKE '%$title%' OR post LIKE '%$title%'') 
      OR (title LIKE '%$post%' OR post LIKE '%$post%'') 
      AND id != '$id'");
```

I want use it as related articles

Comment: 1. where is result showing code?  2. run this query directly to mysql and check record are coming or not (hard-code variables value)? 3. stop using `mysql_*` turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some wrong quotes and use concat for the like string

```
"SELECT * 
  FROM  pvl_posts 
  WHERE (title LIKE concat('%', '$title','%') OR post LIKE concat('%','$title' ,'%') )
  OR (title LIKE concat('%' , '$post', '%')   OR post LIKE concat('%','$post','%') )
  AND id != '$id'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
$rela=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  pvl_posts WHERE (title LIKE '%".$title."%' OR post LIKE '%".$title."%') OR (title LIKE '%".$post."%' OR post LIKE '".$post."') AND id != '".$id."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,there is two `'` ,remove it.

```
$rela=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  pvl_posts WHERE (title LIKE '%$title%' OR post LIKE '%$title%') OR (title LIKE '%$post%' OR post LIKE '%$post%') AND id != '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly show your mysql connection string. here is an example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database_name");
$query = "SELECT * FROM  pvl_posts WHERE (title LIKE '%$title%' OR post LIKE '%$title%') OR (title LIKE '%$post%' OR post LIKE '%$post%') AND id != '$id'";
$rows = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($rows->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do something with row variable here.
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
?>
```

Try it out.